# Algorithm for random sampling under multiple no-repeat conditions

Tags: algorithm, sorting, combinatorics, sampling

I ran into the following issue:

So, I got an array of 100-1000 objects (size varies), e.g.something like

```
[{one:1,two:'A',three: 'a'}, {one:1,two:'A',three: 'b'}, {one:1,two:'A',three: 'c'}, {one:1,two:'A',three: 'd'},
{one:1,two:'B',three: 'a'},{one:2,two:'B',three: 'b'},{one:1,two:'B',three: ':c'}, {one:1,two:'B',three: 'd'},
{one:1,two:'C',three: 'a'},{one:1,two:'C',three: 'b'},{one:1,two:'C',three: ':c'}, {one:2,two:'C',three: 'd'},
{one:1,two:'C',three: 'a'},{one:1,two:'C',three: 'b'},{one:2,two:'C',three: ':c'}, {one:1,two:'C',three: 'd'},...]
```

The value for 'one' is pretty much arbitrary. 'two' and 'three' have to be balanced in a certain way: Basically, in the above, there is some n, such that n=4 times 'A'. 'B','C','D','a','b','c' and 'd' - and such an n exists in any variant of this problem. It is just not clear what the n is, and the combinations themselves can also vary (e.g. if we only had As and Bs, [{1,A,a},{1,A,a},{1,B,b},{1,B,b}] as well as [{1,A,a},{1,A,b},{1,B,a},{1,B,b}] would both be possible arrays with n=2).

What I am trying to do now, is randomise the original array with the condition that there cannot be repeats in close order for some keys, i.e. the value of 'two' and 'three' for an object at index i-1 cannot be the same as the value of same attribute for the object at index i (and that should be true for all or as many objects as possible), i.e. [{1,B,a},{1,A,a},{1,C,b}] would not be allowed, [{1,B,a},{1,C,b},{1,A,a}] would be allowed.

I tried some brute-force method (randomise all, then push wrong indexes to the back) that works rarely, but it mostly just loops infinitely over the whole array, because it never ends up without repeats. Not sure, if this is because it is generally mathematically impossible for some original arrays, or if it is just because my solution sucks.

By now, I've been looking for over a week, and I am not even sure how to approach this.
Would be great, if someone knew a solution for this problem, or at least a reason why it isn't possible. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So `one` places no constraints? You're just wondering how to do `two`, which cannot have duplicate items beside each other, and `three`, which also cannot have duplicate items beside each other? And `n` is related to generating the sequence?

Comment: Whatever is in `one` can be completely arbitrary, but the objects themselves are predetermined by the original set. So, we can have e.g. [{1,A,b}, {5,B,b}, {13,A,c}, {31,A,b}], but when you randomise this, the objects have to still be "intact" after that whole randomisation process. 
There can be as many duplicates as possible. The only rule is, that any value for `two` and `three` has the same amount of occurences (if we got n=4 objects with `two : "A"`, then there are also 4 objects with `two: "B"`, `two: "C"`, and `two: "D"` - and same applies for `three` ). So `n` is just the condition.

Comment: `one`, `two`, and `three` are completely independent, though? So say, `n=2`, there would have to be an even number, and 2 of each letter, `n=3`, multiple of 3 and 3 each? Or a multiple of 3?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with independent in this context. Stochastically, I guess they would be dependent if you draw objects randomly. 
The original sets are already such that this condition with `n` is fulfilled. So, at no point, there is a need to check that condition again (it might be useful for the purpose of running an algorithm that doesn't loop, though). 
The problem is not creating a new set with the `n`-condition, it is sorting an existing set.

Comment: So the first example, only 1 Hamiltonan path exists, `[Aa, Bb, Aa, Bb]`, so you have to choose this, the 2nd, `[Aa, Bb][Ab, Ba]` admits no solution?

Answer (score 1):

First, let us dissect the problem.
Forget for now about `one`, separate `two` and `three` into two independent sequences (assuming they are indeed independent, and not tied to each other).
The underlying problem is then as follows.

Given is a collection of c1 `A`s, c2 `B`s, c3 `C`s, and so on. Place them *randomly* in such a way that no two consecutive letters are the same.

The trivial approach is as follows.
Suppose we already placed some letters, and are left with d1 `A`s, d2 `B`s, d3 `C`s, and so on.
What is the condition when it is impossible to place the remaining letters?
It is when the count for one of the letters, say dk, is greater than one plus the sum of all other counts, 1 + d1 + d2 + ... excluding dk.
Otherwise, we can place them as K . K . K . K ..., where K is the k-th letter, and dots correspond to any letter except the k-th.
We can proceed at least as long as dk is still the greatest of the remaining quantities of letters.

So, on each step, if there is a dk equal to 1 + d1 + d2 + ... excluding dk, we should place the k-th letter right now.
Otherwise, we can place any other letter and still be able to place all others.
If there is no immediate danger of not being able to continue, adjust the probabilities to your liking, for example, weigh placing k-th letter as dk (instead of uniform probabilities for all remaining letters).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But as I mentioned, the combinations of the attributes vary depending on the original array and are not completely random, so `three` and `two` are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

This problem smells of NP complete and lots of hard combinatorial optimization problems.

Just to find a solution, I'd always place as the next element the remaining element that can be placed which as few possible remaining elements can be placed next to.  In other words try to get the hardest elements out of the way first - if they run into a problem, then you're stuck.  If that works, then you're golden.  (There are data structures like a heap which can be used to find those fairly efficiently.)

Now armed with a "good enough" solver, I'd suggest picking the first element randomly until the solver can solve the rest.  Repeat.  If at any time you find it takes too many guesses, just go with what the solver did last time.  That way all the way you know that there IS a solution, even though you are trying to do things randomly at every step.

Answer (score 0):

### Graph

As I understand it, `one` does not play a role in constraints, so I'll label `{one:1,two:'A',three: 'a'}` with *Aa*. Thinking of objects as vertices, place them on a graph. Place edges whenever two respective vertices can be beside each other. For `[{1,A,a},{1,A,a},{1,B,b},{1,B,b}]` it would be,

[image: A box.]

and for `[{1,A,a},{1,A,b},{1,B,a},{1,B,b}]`,

[image: Disconnected.]

The problem becomes: select a random [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), (if possible.) For the loop, it would be any path on the circuit *[Aa, Bb, Aa, Bb]* or the reverse. For the disconnected lines, it is not possible.

### Possible algorithm

I think, to be uniformly random, we would have to enumerate all the possibilities and choose one at random. This is probably infeasible, even at 100 vertices.

A näive algorithm that relaxes the uniform criterion, I think, would be to select (a) random point that does not split the graph in two. Then select (b) random neighbour of (a) that does not split the graph in two. Remove (a) to the solution. (a) = (b). Keep going until the end or backtrack when there are no moves, (if possible.) There may be further heuristics that could cut down the branching factor.

### Example

[image: Ab, Ab, Ca, Bc, Ba, Cc]

There are no vertices that would disconnect the graph, so choosing `Ab` uniformly at random.

[image: Choosing Ab randomly.]

The neighbours of `Ab` are *{Ca, Bc, Ba, Cc}* of which *Ca* is chosen randomly.

[image: Ca]

*Ab* splits the graph, so we must choose *Bc*.

[image: Bc]

The only choice left is which of *Cc* and *Ba* comes first. We might end up with: *[Ab, Ca, Bc, Ab, Ba, Cc]*.